# How CERT.rsa is interrelated with PackageInfo signatures

Tags: certificates, public-key-infrastructure, android, java

I am a newbie in security and cryptography, but I  am developing Android applications and now wanna to dive deeper into the Android security mechanisms. I am trying to understand how CERT.rsa (as I know this public key from key pair) and signature returned by package manager are interconnected.

```
PackageInfo packageInfo = appContext.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(appContext.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
            Signature[] signatures = packageInfo.signatures;
            Log.d(TAG,"Signature" + signatures[0].toString());
```

In case of retrieving signature with package manager I get array of bytes with length > 700. In case of self signed debug key I get something like this

```
bytes[48, -126, 3, 13, 48, -126, 1, -11, -96, 3, 2, 1, 2, 2, 4, 102, -106, 43, -72, 48, 13, 6, 9, ...........
```

I have tried to extract and view information about public key CERT.rsa file from META-INF folder.
I used following command to get it.

```
openssl pkcs7 -in CERT
.RSA -print_certs -inform DER -out foo.cer
```

my foo.cert file contains following information

```
subject=/C=US/O=Android/CN=Android Debug
issuer=/C=US/O=Android/CN=Android Debug
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIDDTCCAfWgAwIBAgIEZpYruDANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADA3MQswCQYDVQQGEwJV
UzEQMA4GA1UEChMHQW5.......
```

Or in hexdecimal `30 82 01 0A 02 82 01 01 00 8A 24 24 1A F1 0B 5D 85 56 FE 35 17 50 90 5E F9 BF BA 2D 36 83 3C 0A 9A 56 4B 91 71 3A 48 E3 CB CE 25 73 76 C4 7F 1C 8B A7 5C F0 C3 52 6D E0 35 5A CC 10 C3 54 E5 DE 57 80 BF 6E`

My primary question is: Where does the PackageManager get this signature info?

Answer (score 3):

It is the last block of Hex from the following command:

```
openssl pkcs7 -inform DER -in CERT.RSA -noout -print_certs -text
```